# Shouldn't this の particle be a に particle?

Tags: particle-に, particle-の

I understand the gist of what the final sentence is, but I don't understand why の was used instead of に. Is it because the 間 represents a sense of "when" (just as 'いつ' in いつ行きますか does), therby not allowing the use of the に particle?

> 夜は、英語の特訓。新聞や雑誌が読み書きの教材に、雑音混じりのラジオ番組が会話の教材にされた。食事や休憩の間は、アインは英語しか話さない。日本語を使ってくれるのは、講義**の**間だけ。

Comment: `食事や休憩の間` の 「の」は気にならなかったんですね・・

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like 食事や休憩**の**間は in your example, it should be 講義**の**間だけ, not *講義に間だけ.

The の connects two nouns, just like English "of" does.

> [名詞¹] + の + [名詞²] = Noun² + of + Noun¹
> [休憩]{きゅうけい}**の**[間]{あいだ} -- *lit.* time **of** break → during the break
> [講義]{こうぎ}**の**[間]{あいだ} -- *lit.* time **of** lecture → during the lecture
> [英語]{えいご}**の**[特訓]{とっくん} -- intensive training **of** English
> [会話]{かいわ}**の**[教材]{きょうざい} -- material **of** conversation

Comment: It was a hour after posting my question that I realized that the no particle was supposed to be there, and translated the sentence as 'She takes the trouble to use Japanese, only during lectures.' I'm glad to see I wasn't mistaken.